# PN532 board connected to RPi 2B. Not working with NTAG tags?

Tags: nfc

Recently I bought [this board](http://www.elechouse.com/elechouse/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=90_93&products_id=2242) (at least it looks like that). I connected the board with my RPi 2B via I2C. I compiled and installed libnfc and libfreefare. The board came with 2 ISO14443A tags (non-NTAG215), and it read them with no problem. However the board wouldn't detect NTAG215 tags. When I run `ntag-detect` (in libfreefare), there's simply no output. What can I do to fix this?

I've read [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/63850/42413). Does that apply to my case?

Comment: ntag512? or ntag215?

Comment: @JaromandaX Ha, silly me. Should be 215.